How to get detailed documentation on the setup and cleanup procedure of CPython interpreter?
I'm running a multiprocessing application with Python, and have a hard time cleaning up the resource after the program finishes. My program has many interaction with C library, and I need to make sure resources in the C library are released properly.
Therefore, I would like to know the setup and cleanup process of Python interpreter:

From OS created the process, until Python interpreter starts to run bytecode, what happens in between?
When a program exits, or being interrupted by signals, what is the cleanup order of objects in Python?

I searched the python documentation page, and find little resource on this.

Requests for links to off-site resources, including documentation, are categorically off-topic here. Do you have a specific technical problem that understanding this will help you solve? Ask a question about that problem, with a [MRE], instead.

(Note that much of deallocation order is deliberately implementation-defined and subject to change without notice; we'd need considerable detail to determine if you're in a case where there exists documented/defined/guaranteed behavior)

Okay, I have a more specific problem: when we call Process() in Python, what happened to that Process?
I mean, usually we use python script.py to start, and I know OS will start a process to run python, which will read script.py and execute it. But what happens to multiprocessing? Which executable does it use? Which script file does it start to run?

(See the "Bugs and Caveats" section of the documentation for PyFinalize_Ex if you're looking for an explicit statement that deallocation order is random)

Multiprocessing is a larger topic -- it has several different modes with very different behavior, and which one is default depends on your OS. Ask a question with a full reproducer stating the specific OS it applies to and it'll be easier to answer in specifics

(Personally, I live in UNIX-land, so I'm more familiar with forking mode -- where the parent process does your initialization, then fork()s off a bunch of child processes, each of which gets a copy of the parent's memory / file descriptors / resources / etc without rerunning initialization; whereas on Windows the default mode has each child process invoked from scratch and thus rerunning initialization).

...because forking mode copies file descriptors, it gets... interesting... when you have things like sockets being forked, so there are a lot of intricate corner cases we'd need to know details of your application to speak to -- depending on what it's doing they may or not matter -- and if you're not on a UNIXy platform and can't use forking mode at all, then this is of course entirely moot.
